# Problem similar to Feynman disk paradox. (violation of conservation of angular momentum)

Tags: electromagnetism, angular-momentum, conservation-laws

I have a problem(paradox) similar to Feynman disk paradox. There is a example similar to Feynman disk paradox in Griffiths electrodynamics. Example 8.4 shows that the initial angular momentum of electromagnetic field is equal to the final angular momentum of two cylinders. Then, what happens if there was no inner cylinder?

Now, there is a long solenoid with radius $R$, $n$ turns per unit length, and current $I$. Coaxial long cylinder with radius $b>R$ carries uniformly distributed charge $Q$. In this situation, there is no initial angular momentum of electromagnetic field since electric field only exists in the region $s>b$, while magnetic field exists in the region $s<R$. However, when the current is reduced to zero, the induced electric field will cause torque to the charge of cylinder, therefore cylinder will rotate and final angular momentum won't be zero. This violates the conservation of angular momentum. How can be this paradox resolved?

Comment: Is either of our cylinders fixed in place by an external torque?

Comment: Cylinder can rotate freely about its center axis

Comment: If the solenoid is fixed, then there is an external torque which prevents it from rotating.  With an external torque, angular momentum is not conserved.